# Getting data from str in json

Tags: python, json, api, formatting

I need to get data from JSON and transform it to csv, but the JSON that is coming from API kind of strange:

```
{'response': {'data': {'normalized': [{'continued': [{'G1': None,
                                                     'G2': None,
                                                      ...
```

Expected result would be something looking like this:

```
{'response': {'data': {'normalized': {'continued': {'G1': None,
                                                     'G2': None,
                                                      ...
```

or this:

```
{'G1': None,
'G2': None,
...
```

I have tried using this function:

```
def flattenjson(b, delim):
    val = {}
    for i in b.keys():
        if isinstance(b[i], dict):
            get = flattenjson(b[i], delim)
            for j in get.keys():
                val[i + delim + j] = get[j]
        else:
            val[i] = b[i]
            
    return val
```

which flattens data from JSON and changes its column name, but it didn't work as it was supposed and gave this mistake:

```
    129 def flattenjson(b, delim):
    130     val = {}
--> 131     for i in b.keys():
    132         if isinstance(b[i], dict):
    133             get = flattenjson(b[i], delim)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I am not sure what the problem is and would be thankful for any suggestions

Comment: Why not use `loads` method from built-in `json` module?

Comment: I suppose that you are passing the json data as string to the function, try: json.loads(JsonData)

Comment: _the JSON that is coming from API kind of strange_ - it's unclear if you expect different [format of the] response from the API or whether you are confused of the outcome after you process the response. If the API response uses list(s), then probably there is good reason why, i.e. multiple objects/elements.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.